# Saving color int from ColorPicker Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, color-picker

I'm working with `ColorPicker` in Android. When I set desired color from my `ColorPicker` it works. But when I quit and restart my `activity` again my color gets back to default. I've been working on this problem over 2 weeks now, and tried every single thing from `SharedPreferences`! Here's my code:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.project;

import yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog;
import yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Preferences extends Activity {

    String[] pref_list = { "Background Color", "Background Wallpaper" };
    RelativeLayout background;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefs";
    Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);

        background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.p_rl);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.lv_activity, pref_list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pref_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {

                    colorpicker();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void colorpicker() {

        AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, 0xff0000ff,
                new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                        SharedPreferences sharedpreference = getApplicationContext()
                                .getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        Editor editor = sharedpreference.edit();
                        editor.putInt("Color code", color);
                        editor.commit();
                        Preferences.this.findViewById(R.id.p_rl)
                                .setBackgroundColor(color);
                        Preferences.this.findViewById(R.id.pref_list)
                                .setBackgroundColor(color);

                    }

                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void run(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreference = getSharedPreferences(
                MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedpreference.getInt("Color code", 0);

        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

But it's not simply working! What's wrong in my code?

Comment: No one wants to help?

Answer (score 0):

Change your onItemClick listener like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("color", position).commit();
        if (position == 0) {

            //colorpicker();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
        }
    }
});
```

And add this to the onCreate

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
int selectedColor = sharedpreference.getInt("color", 0);
listView.setItemChecked(selectedColor, true);
```

Comment: It's force closing. Please can you show me detailed answer, I've been STUCKED on this problem from many weeks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data you save on sharedPreference on onCreate or onResume.
So once the app starts you apply whatever colour you saved.

Comment: Please can you show me how to do it? I'll be VERY thankful to you!

Comment: Make sharedpreference a global variable
move this code to onCrreate `sharedpreference = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);`
then `sharedpreference.getInt("Color code", 0);`

Comment: `int t = sharedpreference.getInt("Color code", 0)
Preferences.this.findViewById(R.id.p_rl) .setBackgroundColor(colorCode);
Preferences.this.findViewById(R.id.pref_list).setBackgroundColor(colorCode);`

Comment: But I'm not able to make my int color global, that's the HUGE problem!

Comment: you dont have to make it global. you already saved it in your sharedpreference. sharedpreference data will persist until you clear the app data or uninstall it. the code below will get the colour code you saved in you shared preference


`int colorCode = sharedpreference.getInt("Color code", 0) Preferences.this.findViewById(R.id.p_rl) .setBackgroundColor(colorCode); Preferences.this.findViewById(R.id.pref_list).setBackgroundColor(colorCode); `

this will be on onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

```
  //add param in that function
  public void colorpicker(int color) { 

        AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, color,
                new OnAmbilWarnaListener() { 
        //your code
        }
  }


  //call this function in that way:
  colorpicker(getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("Color code", 0xff0000ff));
```

So just use saved data. Currently you don't do that.

Comment: And when should I call the function?

Comment: I don't know when you need it. When you need to show this dialog? Btw, do you see that it is your code, just slightly modified?

Comment: On listview item click it shows up a dialog, but when I add int color to colorpicker() I'm unable to call the dialog!

Comment: Just copy-past my code. Everything is done for you already. Don't you see that function signature also was modified?

Comment: Means I have a listview, and when user selects one of the option the ColorPicker dialog pops out, but as I've added `int color` to the `colorpicker()` I'm unable to call the method by `if (position == 0) {

                    colorpicker();
                }`

Comment: Check last line of code in my answer and replace colorpicker() with it.